# What's the difference between XX Volt and XX Volt MAX on rechargeable lithium ion batteries?

Tags: powertools, lawn-mower, battery

I was looking at battery power tools and their different battery voltages. Some of the voltages are listed twice, with and without "max". An example for mowers is "40-volt" and "40-volt max". What's the difference between the voltages with "max" and without "max"?

[image: battery voltages]

Comment: What brands are you looking at it may have something to do with the style of the battery contacts , I have a 6 ah battery that the contacts look the same as the 2 ah batteries the difference is each cell is larger.

Comment: What website is this?  Most likely those categories are just echoing the text in the advertising blurbs for the products found.  It's possible, tho' a bit unlikely that, e.g., a "40 V max" tool would function with a  24-V battery, but my guess is just poor English.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Lowes.

Comment: This isn't a question about batteries.  This is a question about a website's search engine.  There are a variety of reasons to allow ranges in search filters.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica not sure I agree with you. I pulled up the Lowes site and "20 volt max" yields a set of 7 brands, while the "20 volt" yields a _different_ set of 7 brands. "Max" is all about marketing 'cause "Max" sounds... maxier...

Comment: And I checked - there is at least one yellow & black brand product that exists in the "20-volt" line that's not listed in the "20 volt max" line. Oh, maybe it is a web-site issue. I looked the product up on the yellow/black site and the mfgr lists it as a "20-volt Max"

Answer (score 1):

There is one brand of "20-volt Max" tools that reasonably clearly state on their packaging something to the effect of:

> Battery provides 20 volt maximum starting power. Provides 18-volts in use.

As a matter of fact, they'll sell you a simple physical adapter (and some wiring between the contacts) that will allow you to use the "20-volt max" batteries on their older 18-volt line of tools.

#### TL;DR:

"Max" is 98.475% marketing because "Max" sounds, well, like *more* than "not-max". *(And 99.238% of all statistics on the internet are made up on the spot.)*

Comment: Presumably that "20 V starting" is the rating of their battery, not the tool's draw.

Comment: Yes it is, @CarlWitthoft. I don't remember the exact wording at the moment and can't be bothered to go look at the DeWa... (oops) site right now to get it. :)

Comment: Edited to make it more explicit

Comment: Is that like my "6HP" shop vac that draws 10 amps at 120 v  LOL?

Comment: Most assuredly, @GeorgeAnderson

Comment: The "20V" claim is entirely bogus.  Li-Ion batteries have a cell voltage of 3.6V nominal which divides evenly into 18V (i.e. 5) but not into 20.  So there is no way to get 20V out of a 5S battery pack which these "Max" cells are.  It's marketing hype!

Comment: Yes, yes it is, @jwh20.

Comment: BTW, I'm not saying these tools are bad, just that the claims being made don't stand up to scrutiny.

Comment: Also agree, 100% @jwh20. I'm fond of my particular "max" tools, no matter what voltage the batteries put out. I've had precisely 1 problem with the huge mass of 'em that I've owned over the last 15+ years. (Includes the 18-volt, non-max versions...)

Comment: The “max” may simply designate a different and incompatible battery socket.